# How to get colors in order on the divs using arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want these colors to loop in order of colors given. But it gives me only green on all my divs.

```
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  $("div").each(function() {
    $("div").css({
      'background-color': colors[i]
    });
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
```

Comment: You are performing an update on *all* divs three times, therefore the last one wins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually simplify your code and just use the `index` from the [`.each()` method](https://api.jquery.com/each/). It's worth pointing out that the first parameter that is passed in the `.each()` method is the `index`, and the second is a reference to the current element.

If you have more than three items, you can also use `i % colors.length` in order to start back at the beginning of the array after the third index.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/umfftrmp/)

```js
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
$("div").each(function(i) {
  $(this).css('background-color', colors[i % colors.length]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
<div>D</div>
<div>E</div>
```

Comment: I delete my answer because it seem that i wrote same if your answer

Comment: Thanks all. `i %` was a game changer

Answer (score 2):

You are performing the iteration twice, applying the same changes to **all** divs at once. Just use `.each()`:

```
var colors = ["red","blue","green"];
$('div').each(function(i){
  $(this).css('background-color', colors[i]);
});
```

In case the length of your colors does not match the number of your divs you can use the modulo operator to start from 0 when no color is left:

```
$(this).css('background-color', colors[i % colors.length]);
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to index on `(i%colors.length)` in case there are more divs than colors.

Comment: Good point, yet probably too confusing for such a bare bones example.

Answer (score 2):

Use the relative `this` and remove the `for`:

```
var colors = ["red","blue","green"];
$("div").each(function(i) {
  $(this).css({
    'background-color': colors[i % colors.length]
  });
});
```

**Snippet**

I have given `i % colors.length` as the array index, because it makes sure, you are under the boundaries of the `colors` array length.

```js
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
$("div").each(function(i) {
  $(this).css({
    'background-color': colors[i % colors.length]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
<div>D</div>
<div>E</div>
<div>F</div>
<div>G</div>
<div>H</div>
```

It repeats for any number of `<div>`s.

**Preview:**

[image]